# How can i add data in a word document to Android text view?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a word document with 2 paragraph.The document is in ASCII font.How can i display all data in a single android application page?

I have already created an app.in which when i press a button i want to show the data in the document.can anyone help me please.

I am not much aware in android program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Word `.DOC` files do not contain plain-text.  Also, ASCII is not a font, it is a character set.  You either need to convert the Word document to plain-text, or import a library that can handle `.DOC` files, in order to display it in your activity.